# Recursive power (mathematical operation) function in C

Tags: c, recursion, mathematics

#### How to make a C recursive exponentiation (power) function better?

I developed a pretty simple (yet decent, imo) power function for the sake of learning. I'm not *quite* trying to compete with `math.h`'s `double pow(double __x, double __y)`

```c
double pwr(double _base, double _exp)
{
    if (_exp == 0)
        return 1;
    
    else if (_exp > 0)
        return _base * pwr(_base, _exp - 1);
    else
        return 1 / (_base * pwr(_base, (_exp * -1) - 1));
}
```

But i would like to know why (if) `math.h`'s would be better.
Some community guy also told me it could be further simplified, but didn't tell me how. Is that true?

**Note:** I'm aware of "divide and conquer" approach, but not sure how to proceed in case `_exp` is not integer

Answer (score 2):

For large exponents, this code is slower than necessary (it scales linearly in `exp`, rather than logarithmically as an efficient implementation would).  Research **Binary Exponentiation** algorithm, and **Exponentiation by logarithm**, which is what your standard library implementation is most likely to use for `pow(double, double)`.

The latter relies on the identity \$\ln{(y^x)} ≡ x \ln{(y)}\$.  So \$y^x = \exp(x \ln(y))\$.

The implementation here will never return when `exp` is not an integer - you'll just alternate between calls either side of zero, until you run out of stack.  We need to use the logarithm approach for non-integer powers (and arrange to fail when the base is negative and the power is fractional).

Avoid using *reserved identifiers* in your own code.  This includes names that begin with underscore (`_`) followed by a lower-case letter.  (Not as dangerous as names beginning with `_` and an upper-case letter, which are available to the implementation for use as macros, but still not good; as a general rule, never declare your own names beginning with `_` and you'll be fine).

Comment: afaik, reserved identifiers, in C follow this rule:

`According to the C Standard, 7.1. 3 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011], All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.`

since my identifiers start with single `_`and lowercase, i should be fine, no?

Comment: Yes.  Underscore and lowercase letter only reserved for use as identifiers with file scope (the following sentence).  Still worth avoiding in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

For `exp` not 0, between -1 and 1 it will make a recursive call with a negated exponent.

Furthermore **x²ⁿ = (xⁿ)²** which can be used to reduce *n* recursions down to *log₂(n)* recursions.

For **exp = n + q, n int, 0 < q < 1** or **exp = n ± q, n int, 0 < q <= 0.5** you can use **x<sup>exp</sup> = (x<sup>n</sup>).(x<sup>q</sup>)**. For the integer power *n* you can do the logarithmic recursion (`double`, `long` or `BigInteger`). For the *q* fraction you need an approximation sequence. *Don't ask me how.*

Underscore at the beginning, is extra. Nowadays the majority seems to find this *less* readable (as not a ubiquitous convention), and disruptive in reading. Less is more here.

Answer (score 1):

`pow(double _base, double _exp)`, like this `pwr()`, is a challenging function.

Also an accurate implementation is difficult as errors in manipulating `_base` are heavily amplified by large `_exp`.

**Non-integer power**

When `_exp` is not a whole number value, best to use `exp2(_exp * log2(_base))` and avoid `log(), exp()` to improve accuracy.

Note: `_base < 0` will error as, in general, the result of `pow(negative_base, some_non_whole_number)` is a *complex number*.

**`else` not needed**

```
double pwr(double _base, double _exp) {
  if (_exp == 0)
    return 1;
  // else if (_exp > 0)
  if (_exp > 0)
    return _base * pwr(_base, _exp - 1);
  // else
  return 1 / (_base * pwr(_base, (_exp * -1) - 1));
```

**Linear recursion depth**

Should `_exp` be a large integer value, code will recurse *many times*.

Instead, halve the exponent each each recursion for a log recursion depth.

```
// return _base * pwr(_base, _exp - 1);
double p2 = pwr(_base, _exp/2);
return p2*p2*(_exp/2 ? _base : 1);
```

This also improves correctness as fewer calculations are done.

---

**Somewhat improved code**

```
double pwr_rev2(double base, double expo) {
  // If non-integer expo, use exp2(),log2()
  double expo_ipart;
  double fpart = modf(expo, &expo_ipart);
  if (fpart) {
    return exp2(expo * log2(base));
  }

  if (expo_ipart < 0.0) {
    // Form 1/ result
    return 1.0/pwr_rev2(base, -expo);
  }

  if (expo_ipart == 0.0) {
    return 1.0;
  }

  double p = pwr_rev2(base, expo_ipart / 2.0);
  p *= p;
  if (fmod((expo_ipart, 2)) {
    p *= base;
  }
  return p;
}
```

Implementation still has short comings with `1.0/pwr_rev2(base, -expo)` as the quotient becomes 0.0 when the result should be very small, yet more than zero.

It also recurses too many times when the result `p *= p;` is infinity.  TBD code to fix.